# Why is a reference to EntityFramework.dll of my EF data class library project required?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am using the ADO.NET Entity Framework (EF5) in a class library so that it can be accessed by multiple projects. I have used the approach as demonstrated at msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716677(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716677(v=vs.100).aspx

However when using the data library in a separate console app like in this simple example, I get the following error:

```
Sub Main()
    Using Context As New DataModel.Entities
        Console.WriteLine((From User As DataModel.User In Context.Users Where User.Id = 1 Select User.Name()).SingleOrDefault)
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image]

If I let VS fix it and make the reference the problem is solved. However I am concerned that it may give rise to problems later on. What is the right thing to do to prevent it? And do I need to worry at all?

Comment: is DataModel.Context a static class / instance of class in another project that returns EF object (db context)?

Comment: You don't have to worry. When you create an `exe`, the EntityFramework dll is only copied once.

Comment: @YuliamChandra: The DataModel.Context is the default DbContext generated by the EF framework. it must be instantiated before it can be used cf. `Using Context As New DataModel.Entities`

Comment: @Loetn: great, good to know! You know why this happens? I found it difficult to find particular information by googling, but I probably don't know enough about to search effectively.

Comment: @SuppaiKamo You have to add the reference to every project that uses EF because otherwise that specific project doesn't know what to do or expect of type `DbSet<T>`. It's just needed for the compiler.

Comment: A refers B (which also refers EF), whenever you use B in A that returns EF object, then A has to refers EF too